# Force Application class to close

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-testing

I have a class that extends Application. The class is fairly extensive.  When the application is in the background for a long time the OS kills the class.  On restart things go sideways.  I need to debug some data structures and fix the problem.  Is there a way to force the OS to replicate this behavior instead of waiting an hour or two between each time I run the app?  I know I can kill the entire application but that isn't what I'm going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can do this with the emulator with the [Dev Tools App](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html) (look under **Immediately destroy activities**), and you can do it with Ice Cream Sandwich phones (Settings -> Developer Options, Don't keep activities check box).

Comment: This caused my application to crash after going to the home screen and reentering my application. That's a good thing :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> When the application is in the background for a long time the OS kills the class.

No, when the application is in the background for some period of time, the OS terminates your process.

> Is there a way to force the OS to replicate this behavior instead of waiting an hour or two between each time I run the app?

You can terminate the process from DDMS.

> I know I can kill the entire application but that isn't what I'm going for.

Yes, it is, since there is no concept of "kills the class".

Comment: If I terminate the entire process, things run fine.  Also, my Activity at startup works fine.  However, my singleton Application class seems to be the source of all the issues.  Other posts that I've seen have referenced this class's lifecycle not behaving the same as activities.  If this isn't the case, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  My application works fine if you put it to the background and bring it back as well as if you kill it and restart it.

Comment: @EricCrump: "Other posts that I've seen have referenced this class's lifecycle not behaving the same as activities." -- it doesn't really have much of a "lifecycle". It is created when your process is forked (just after creating any `ContentProviders` of yours and before doing anything else), and it lives until the process is terminated.

Comment: @commonsware. I think the asker was just being imprecise, saying "kills the class" rather than calling onDestroy() on the activity. I think they want to know how to test/debug when your activty is destroyed by the OS. And there is an easy way to do that with a setting in the emulator. (see the answer provided by wsanville below.)

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon: The OP specifically (and repeatedly) refers to `Application`. I am assuming the OP is accurate on that point.

Comment: @EricCrump: You might consider opening up another SO question, where you supply more concrete details regarding "go sideways", such as stack traces and related code listings.

Comment: @EricCrump: Another thing you could try to reproduce the problem is use a task killer. If you are on Android 2.2+, task killers should do the same thing as what Android does when it gets rid of a process due to low memory conditions.

Comment: My application originally crashed when it was restarted after being in the background for a long period of time.  I discovered that the problem was that I had a constructor in my Application class.  I removed this and now it doesn't crash.  However, I'm struggling to figure out what the problem is now.  That is why I want to reproduce what the OS is doing in a shorter amount of time.  I (obviously) don't understand what the OS is doing differently when my app is dormant for a long period of time and when it is just killed and restarted. I will try @wsanville solution below to see if that helps

Comment: @commonsware - well, you persuaded me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Programatically to close your app from other class you can call this method:

```
 public static void killApp() {       
                //Notify the system to finalize and collect all objects of the app.
                System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
                //Force the system to close the app down completely.
                System.exit(0);
      }
```